# BigQuery: Persistent UDF with optional parameters

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, optional-parameters

I'm using the persisten UDF functions, but not sure how to make them using optional parameters, like default value.

For example a simple function replacing `NaN`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
`my_project.functions.ifnan`(number ANY TYPE, default_value ANY TYPE) 
AS 
(
if(is_nan(number),default_value,number)
);
```

How can I make it work like `ifnan(value)` returning `0` by default and only if other default value specified overwrite the `0`?

Something like `ifnan(number [,default value])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#temporary-udf-syntax) we can see that for both `SQL` and `JavaScript` UDFs this kind of structure is not specified.

In the SQL syntax:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] [TEMPORARY | TEMP] FUNCTION [IF NOT EXISTS]
    [[`project_name`.]dataset_name.]function_name
    ([named_parameter[, ...]])
  [RETURNS data_type]
  AS (sql_expression)

named_parameter:
  param_name param_type
```

In the JavaScript syntax:

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] [TEMPORARY | TEMP] FUNCTION [IF NOT EXISTS]
    [[`project_name`.]dataset_name.]function_name
    ([named_parameter[, ...]])
  RETURNS data_type
  LANGUAGE js
  [OPTIONS (library = library_array)]
  AS javascript_code
```

Besides that, we can find the followig statement:

> named_parameter. Consists of a comma-separated param_name and
>   param_type pair. The value of param_type is a BigQuery data type. For
>   a SQL UDF, the value of param_type may also be ANY TYPE.

Hence, it would unfortunately appear that this is not a possibility when using UDFs in `BigQuery`.

If you need any further assistence, please let me know.